# SearchView con RecyclerView Android. No funciona el obtener posición

Tags: java, android-studio, sql-server, material-design

Buenas amigos en el mundo de la programación en Android, resulta que estaba realizando un filtrador (buscador) en mi RecyclerView sobre mi ActionBar, el buscador funciona de maravilla, pero al momento de darle clic al producto y llevar esos datos a otra actividad me devuelve el los datos de otro producto,en lugar del que he dado clic, esto sucede cuando me muestra los datos filtrados, cuando muestra los datos no filtrados no hay problema todo funciona. Quisiera que me dieran una idea de cómo puedo solucionar el error a que soy un novato en Android

```js
//////////////////My MainActivity////////////
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.transition.Explode;
import android.support.transition.Fade;
import android.support.transition.Slide;
import android.support.transition.Transition;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
    ArrayList<Elemento> buscador;
    private EditText et_buscar;

    Spinner spinner;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adap;

    ArrayList<Elemento> listaCard;

    Button btnOrdenar;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /////////////////////SPINER/////////////////////
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiner);
        try{ArrayList<String> NombreC = new ArrayList<>();
            NombreC.add("Selccione una categoria");
            for (int i=0;i<ObtenerCategoria().size();i++){
                NombreC.add(ObtenerCategoria().get(i).getNombre());
            }
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,NombreC);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);}
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error se debe estar conectado a la red del servidor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


       
        recycler=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        btnOrdenar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOrdenar);



        Thread tr = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
               String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
               String URL = "http://192.168.43.57/Publicaciones/WebServiceCarrito.asmx";
               String METHOD_NAME = "ListarProductos";
               String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/ListarProductos";

               SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet=true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                try{
                    transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    final SoapObject soap= (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listarProductos(soap);

                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        };
        tr.start();
        //////////////////////////ON clic
        ((Adaptador) adap).setOnItemClickListener(new Adaptador.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Elemento item = listaCard.get(position);

               // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), item.getDescripcion()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detalle.class);
                i.putExtra("cod", item.getCodigo());
                i.putExtra("nom", item.getNombre());
                i.putExtra("des", item.getDescripcion());
                i.putExtra("pre", item.getPrecio()+"");
                i.putExtra("img", item.getImg());
                i.putExtra("cate",item.getCategoria());
                //////////////////////////////

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //////////////////////////Traer Categorias////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public ArrayList<Categoria> ObtenerCategoria(){
        ArrayList<Categoria> categoria = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Statement st= ConexionBD().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Categoria");
            while (rs.next()){
                categoria.add(new Categoria( rs.getString("nombreC")));
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return categoria;

    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////CONEXION////////////////////////
    public Connection ConexionBD(){
        Connection conexion = null;
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conexion= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.43.57:1433;databaseName=BD_RASOR;user=sa;password=adminroot;");

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        return conexion;
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public  void listarProductos(SoapObject soap){
        listaCard = new ArrayList<Elemento>();

        for (int i=0;i<soap.getPropertyCount(); i++){
            SoapObject reg= (SoapObject)soap.getProperty(i);
            Elemento e1 = new Elemento(reg.getProperty(1).toString(),
                    reg.getProperty(2).toString(),
                    reg.getProperty(3).toString(),
                    Double.parseDouble(reg.getProperty(4).toString()),
                    reg.getProperty(5).toString(),
                    reg.getProperty(6).toString());
            listaCard.add(e1);

        }
        adap=new Adaptador(listaCard,getApplication());

        recycler.setAdapter(adap);



    }

///////////////////////Esta Parte  tengo el buscador////////////////////////////

  public  boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscador,menu);
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.buscador);
      SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
      MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {

          @Override
          public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
              ((Adaptador)adap).setFilter(listaCard);

              return true;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
              return true;
          }
      });
        return  true;
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        try {
        ArrayList<Elemento>listaFiltrada=filter(listaCard,s);
            ((Adaptador)adap).setFilter(listaFiltrada);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
    private ArrayList<Elemento> filter(ArrayList<Elemento> elementos,  String texto){
        ArrayList<Elemento> listaFiltrada=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            texto=texto.toLowerCase();
            for(Elemento elemento : elementos){
                String elemento2=elemento.getNombre().toLowerCase();
                ((Adaptador) adap).setFilter(listaFiltrada);
                if(elemento2.contains(texto)){
                    listaFiltrada.add(elemento);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaFiltrada;
    }
}
```

```js
////Los datos obetenidos en el INTENT los debo de pasar para esta actividad
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.transition.Transition;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Detalle extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imgDetalle;
    TextView txtDetalleNombre, txtDetalleDes, txtDetallePrecio;
    Button btnVer, btnAgregar;
    String cod="",nombre="",des="",img="";
    double pre=0;
///////////////////Arreglo que servirá para agregar los articulos al carrito////
    ArrayList<Elemento> cesta = new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences carrito;
    Gson gson=new Gson();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle);

        imgDetalle =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgDetalle);
        txtDetalleNombre = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDetalleNombre);
        txtDetalleDes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDetallesDes);
        txtDetallePrecio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDetallePrecio);
        btnAgregar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar);
        btnVer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVer);

        Bundle recupera = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (recupera != null){



            try{
                cod = recupera.getString("cod");
                nombre = recupera.getString("nom");
                des = recupera.getString("des");
                pre = Double.parseDouble(recupera.getString("pre"));
                img = recupera.getString("img");
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }



        }
        //////////////////////Recupero en esta parte, 
        pero no me devuelve los valores que he filtrado mediante le buscador. sino los del RecyclerView original/////////////
        if (recupera!=null){
            cod = recupera.getString("cod2");
            nombre = recupera.getString("nom2");
            des = recupera.getString("des2");
            pre = Double.parseDouble(recupera.getString("pre2"));
            img = recupera.getString("img2");
        }
        txtDetalleDes.setText(des);
        txtDetalleNombre.setText(nombre);
        txtDetallePrecio.setText("$"+pre+"");
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://192.168.43.57/Publicaciones/imagenes/"
                +img).resize(720,600).into(imgDetalle);




        //recuperando datos de la preferencia
        File f = new File("/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/shared_prefs/carrito.xml");
        carrito = getSharedPreferences("carrito",MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (f.exists()){
            String guardado = carrito.getString("cesta","");
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Elemento>>(){}.getType();
            cesta=gson.fromJson(guardado,type);
        }


        //////////////para implementar el botón agregar al carrito

        btnAgregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Elemento E = new Elemento(cod,nombre,pre,1);
        if (agregarProducto(E)==true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se aumentó la cantidad ¡Compra más!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se agregó nuevo producto ¡Compra más!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        String listaGson= gson.toJson(cesta);
        carrito =getSharedPreferences("carrito",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = carrito.edit();
        editor.putString("cesta",listaGson);
        editor.commit();
    }
});

        btnVer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                File f = new File("/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/shared_prefs/carrito.xml");

                if(f.exists()){
                    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Cesta.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Carrito de compra vacío",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
    //////////////////Tranciciones////////
    private Transition transition;


////////////////////////////
    private boolean agregarProducto(Elemento E){
        for (int i=0;i<cesta.size();i++){
            if(cesta.get(i).getCodigo().equals(E.getCodigo())){
                cesta.get(i).setCantidad(cesta.get(i).getCantidad()+1);
                return true;
            }
        }
        cesta.add(E);
        return  false;
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que estas obteniendo el item de la lista original con la posicion filtrada. Por ejemplo; Si tengo una lista con los numeros del 1 al 5 . Y en el filtro escribo 5. Me devolvera 1 elemento que representa la posicion 0 del adapter y la posicion 4 de la lista original. Al hacer click quiero que me devuelva el item que representa al numero 5 pero como el adapter me devuelve 0 me va a devolver el item de la lista en esa posicion que es 1. Ese es el error que estas cometiendo. Una opcion es devolver la lista filtrada desde el adapter y obtener el item en el itemclick con la posicion.

Comment: Estas haciendo en el OnItemClick en vez de obtener el item de `Elemento item = listaCard.get(position);` debes hacerlo con la lista filtrada como resultado del filtro. Porque listaCard es la lista original pero las posiciones que te devolvera no son las posiciones originales sino las filtradas.